# Node JS error: Cannot find module '../build/jvm_dll_path.json'

Tags: node.js, npm

I am receiving the following error after running `npm start`:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/jvm_dll_path.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/stature-gqdss/node_modules/java/lib

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with `java` if it is for node?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if the server is already running and kill the existing server.  If no other server is running, try reinstalling your dependencies and try again.

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack here. You can simply create a file named ***jvm_dll_path.json*** inside ***node_modules\java\build*** and paste the path of server to this, between quotes like shown below..

```
";C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdkX.X.X_XXX\\jre\\bin\\server"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me running

> `node postInstall.js`

in the  *node_modules/java* folder worked.

Comment: @jiawang Glad, it worked for you,  It would be great if you can upvote it So that in the future someone will consider it to give it a try. Thanks.